# The data available in the Backend does not come to the Front side

Tags: laravel

[image: Front]
[image: Backend]

Here, the images part is available before sending, but when you respond to the html side, that images part disappears.

looks exactly like this.

My codes.

backend

```
 public function loadMoreReports(Request $request)
    {
        $page = $request->get('page');
        $perPage = 6;

        $reports = ManagementReport::where('reports_status', 'published')
            ->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)
            ->take($perPage)
            ->get();
        $reportsWithImages = $reports->map(function ($report) {
            $images = Media::where('model_type', 'App\Models\ManagementReport')
                ->where('model_id', $report->id)
                ->where('mime_type', 'like', 'image%')
                ->get();

            $slug = Str::slug($report->reports_name);

            return [
                'report' => $report,
                'images' => $images,
            ];
        });
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $reportsWithImages,
            'has_more_pages' => $reports->count() === $perPage,
        ]);

    }
```

Frontend

```
<script>
       var currentPage = 1;
       var loading = false;

       function loadMoreReports() {
           var url = "{{ route('loadMoreReports') }}";

           $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: "GET",
               data: {page: currentPage + 1},
               beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#loadingIndicator').show();
                   loading = true;
               },
               success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response)
                   var reportsWithImages = response.data;
                   var hasMorePages = response.has_more_pages;

                   if (reportsWithImages.length > 0) {
                       var html = '';
                       console.log(reportsWithImages)

                       $.each(reportsWithImages, function(index, item) {
                           html += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">';
                           html += '<a href="{{ route('reportName', ['slug' => 'slug_placeholder', 'id' => 'id_placeholder']) }}'
                                   .replace('slug_placeholder', item.report.slug)
                                   .replace('id_placeholder', item.report.id)
                               + '" class="report-item transition-hover-top report-icon">';

                           // Rapor içeriği ve resimleri buraya eklenecek
                           $.each(item.images, function(imageIndex, image) {
                               console.log(image.getUrl())
                               html += '<div class="img">';
                               html += '<img class="lazyload" data-src="' + image.getUrl() + '" alt="' + item.report.reports_name + '" title="' + item.report.reports_name + '" width="260" height="367">';
                               html += '</div>';
                           });
                           html += '<h3>' + item.report.reports_name + '</h3>';
                           html += '<span title="Read the Report" class="read-more">';
                           html += '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 30 30">';
                           // Read the Report icon SVG içeriği
                           html += '</svg>';
                           html += 'Read the Report';
                           html += '</span>';
                           html += '</a>';
                           html += '</div>';
                       });

                       $('#reportList').append(html);
                       // lazyload için etkinleştirme
                       $('.lazyload').lazyload();
                       currentPage++;
                   }

                   $('#loadingIndicator').hide();
                   loading = false;

                   if (!hasMorePages) {
                       $(window).off('scroll', onScroll);
                   }
               },
               error: function() {
                   $('#loadingIndicator').hide();
                   loading = false;
               }
           });
       }

       function onScroll() {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200 && !loading) {
               loadMoreReports();
           }
       }

       $(document).ready(function() {
           // lazyload için etkinleştirme
           $('.lazyload').lazyload();
           $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
       });
   </script>
```

I have tried to format it, I have done an array conversion, but I still cannot capture the data of these images on the front side, although it is there.

Comment: FYI, instead of ``->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)->take($perPage)`` you could simply use the ``paginate`` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images you are looking in your `dd` are a relation field on the model.
The images you are looking in your `console.log` are from your `map`. Why not do something like this:

```php
$reports = ManagementReport::query()
    ->with(['images'])
    ->where('reports_status', 'published')
    ->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)
    ->take($perPage)
    ->get();

return response()->json([
    'data' => $reports,
    'has_more_pages' => $reports->count() === $perPage,
]);
```